# How to implement short press & long press(or long hold) in android app effectively?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I am creating an android application wherein I have mentioned the phone number, email, website of the business similar to the screenshot of google maps as attached.

Just like in the g maps where

> 1. Single click makes an intent to the respective app (opens dialer with phone number copied) etc.
> 2. Long Click/Press & hold will copy the number to clipboard displaying a toast that "Phone number is copied to clicpboard".

Now I have set up the intents properly and they are working fine --> step-1 achieved.

When I try to display the toast using "OnLongClickListener" method it is taking quite some time to display the toast message. Is there any way we can speed this up or am I missing something or should I use some other alternative like **onTouch()** method?

*(Stuck with this, yet to learn and try out copying to clipboard thing. Inputs in this regards are also welcome!)*

In the g maps app, the toast message appears almost instantly on press & hold. So the same is to be achieved.

[image: Screenshot of Google Maps]

> The code extract from MainActivity.java (The website, phone number, email id are text views with drawableLeft. And I found out that we cannot use setOnItemLongClick on TextView as it is only for ListView)

```
// This method is called when the website text view is clicked and opens the  compnay website

public void openWebsite(View v) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webURL_text_view);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent openWebsiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            openWebsiteIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.company.com"));

            if (openWebsiteIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(openWebsiteIntent);
            }
        }
    });

    textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            showMessage();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Information copied to Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

> I am new to android development and just trying out something, so please be as elaborative as possible. Thank You.